# Issue with turning tuple entry variables into an int for a math problem

Tags: python, integer, tuples, tkinter-entry

currently I've been trying to have my tuple variables: tempLentry,windLentry,dewpointLentry, be converted into an integer so I can use them in the math sequence. However I keep getting this error whenever it happens: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Entry'. I was hoping someone could point in the right direction, Thank you!

The code is below

```
def calc ():    
    #Tuple being recieved from askUser
    tempLentry,windLentry,dewpointLentry = askUser()

    #Converts string input from entries to integers for the calculations to work.
    t = int(tempLentry)
    ws = int(windLentry)
    dp = int(dewpointLentry)

    #Checks to see if inputed data for temperature and windspeed is less than 50mph and 
    greater than 3 mph
    if (t < 50 and ws > 3):
        windchill = (35.74 + 0.6215 * t - (35.75 * math.pow(ws,0.16)) + (0.4275 * t * math.pow(ws,0.16)))
    else:
        windchill = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first convert the Entry to a string, and then cast it to an int.

You can get the Entry as a string by using `.get()`

```
t = int(tempLentry.get())
ws = int(windLentry.get())
dp = int(dewpointLentry.get())
```

Comment: When doing that I get: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: You need to make sure that the user has typed something into the entry, and that they have typed a value that can be parsed as an int.

Comment: The data that is being entered into the entry are numbers only. I would hope numbers can be passed lol

Comment: This is how you do it. Your problem is no longer caused by these lines and it is elsewhere in your code. Print out your tempLentry.get() to confirm your entry contains what you expect it to contain

Comment: Okay thank you, it appears that when a user enters something in the entry, it does retain the value in the tuple.